# Second (centered) moment for martingales

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Take the process ${x}_t$ following geometric Brownian motion (GBM)
$$x_t=\mu x_t \,dt+\sigma x_t \,dW_t$$ with $x_0>0$ known.
It has first moment equal to $$\text{E}[x_t]=x_0 e^{\mu t}$$ and second moment going to zero as $x_0 \to 0$.

Taking a more general process
\begin{equation}dx_t=μ(t,x_t) \,dt+\sigma(t,x_t) \,dW_t,  (1)\end{equation}
is it possible to prove that the second moment is going to zero as $x_0 \to 0$? And, in general, for a Markovian process under a martingale measure, what are the conditions for having second moment converging to zero when $x_0 \to 0$?

Comment: Assuming that $\mu(t,x)\to0$ and $\sigma(t,x)\to0$ when $x\to0$? Otherwise, one sees no reason for the result to hold.

Comment: Are the to conditions sufficient?

Comment: Once again: which setting are you interested in?

Comment: The settings given by equation (1) and assuming  that $\mu(t,x)→0$ and $\sigma(t,x)→0$